# Insert into a vector using an insert using lower_bound

Tags: c++, vector, lower-bound

How do I change CompareByNA to make the insert work, I assume it's wrong for the first element to insert
program: https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3xycp2vju

```
bool Company::compareByNA(const Company &a, const Company &b)
{
    return a.getNameAddr() < b.getNameAddr();
}
..
if ( binary_search(CompanyNameList.begin(), CompanyNameList.end(), cmp, Company::compareByNA) )
    {       
        CompanyNameList.insert(lower_bound(CompanyNameList.begin(), CompanyIDList.end(), cmp, Company::compareByNA), cmp); 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

for example this not work for other elements that I want to insert in order

```
if(CompanyNameList.size() == 0)
   {
        CompanyNameList.push_back(cmp);
        return true;
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?  Doesn't compile?  If so, then post the compiler error.  Also, you don't have to create a separate `compareByNA` function -- use a lambda.

Comment: Segmentation fault, its no difference when i use lambda

Comment: It should work even if it returns end iterator. Where, exactly is the set fault coming from?

Comment: If the collection is empty, `lower_bound` will return `end` which is exactly where you want to insert.  No need for a special case.

Comment: You didn't include nearly enough code here.  We don't know what `CompanyNameList` is or what `GetNameAddr` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is your issue**

```
lower_bound(CompanyNameList.begin(), CompanyIDList.end(), cmp, Company::compareByNA);
```

You are mixing up your lists.
You probably meant to use

```
lower_bound(CompanyNameList.begin(), CompanyNameList.end(), cmp, Company::compareByNA);
```